# Node js pdf-make lib dose support large data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am using this lib the small data process but large data not process it goes to **server crash** 
try catch method also be user but it not catch error

node make *report.json* file
it lib issue any else

Comment: Please mention the code along with expected result and actual result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory limit? Try launch nodejs with `--max-old-space-size=4096` key. It set memory limit to 4GB from default ~1.4GB.

Comment: this command any inpact serve side if yes tell me

Comment: I don't understand. You run nodejs. You get crash no large report. But, you don't get crash on small report. Right?

Comment: right small data not issue large data not process,....................

 --max-old-space-size=4096 this command any inpact other function show down 
at serve

Comment: ```--max-old-space-size=4096``` - launch option. ```nodejs --max-old-space-size=4096 your_script.js scriptarg1 scriptarg2 scriptargn```